# Why does readonly TMOUT in bashrc result in multiple messages on login about TMOUT being readonly?

Tags: linux, bash

After researching the TMOUT variable and various recommendations I set the following in the /etc/bashrc file:

```
TMOUT=600
readonly TMOUT
export TMOUT
```

Now when a user logs in TMOUT gets set to 600, set to readonly and exported          but this error occurs:

```
-bash: TMOUT: readonly variable
-bash: TMOUT: readonly variable
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that `/etc/bashrc` gets sourced more than once -- debug it by adding a

```
echo "TMOUT=<$TMOUT>: ${BASH_SOURCE[*]}"
```

line before your assignment.

AFAIR `/etc/bashrc` is not sourced by default, but explicitly from `~/.bashrc`, and only on RHEL-like distros.

But exporting and making a variable read-only does not work as you apparently expect it to:

```
(readonly FOO=33; export FOO; bash -c 'FOO=47')
  # no error
```

Environment variables don't know about the shell's "readonly" attribute: that will only matter within the current session / script.

This means that a user can bypass your `TMOUT` by simply starting another shell with `env -u TMOUT bash --norc`. Making it read-only is only a nuisance.

Comment: This got me thinking and I saw where /etc/profile and /etc/skel/.bashrc (used when creating new user home dir's) both sourced /etc/bashrc so th at maybe where the duplicate error is coming from.

Comment: As to the user bypassing, this server is for entry level UNIX/Linux students.  If they know how to bypass the TMOUT var then they probably already know  UNIX.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere, you're trying to assign to the variable, but it's now readonly.

You can check whether the variable is readonly using `declare` and only assign to it if it isn't readonly:

```
declare -p TMOUT 2>/dev/null | grep -- '-r' >/dev/null || TMOUT=600
```

The redirections hide the output of `declare` and the error message when the variable hasn't been declared yet.

Comment: when using the above example instead of my original config it works but the TMOUT varable is not readonly.

Comment: You should put the `readonly TMOUT` bellow this line.

Answer (score 0):

OK - Uncle Billy's response nudged me onto the path for resolving this issue.  It seems that both /etc/profile and each user's .bashrc files were both sourcing the /etc/bashrc where the TMOUT variable was being set, exported and made read only. By eliminating the extra calls for sourcing /etc/bashrc I have a resolution.

Thanks for the help choroba and Uncle Billy